# Efficiently replace 0 with NA

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to find a way to *efficiently* replace zero with `NA()` in an Excel formula. I know the following works:

`=IF(FORMULA = 0, NA(), FORMULA)`

But my problem is that this will cause `FORMULA` to execute twice. I have cases where this may be a longer `=SUMIFS()` in a giant table.

So I would like for:

- No VBA
- Only have the base `FORMULA` calculate once

I thought at first to try to use `SUBSTITUTE()` to replace "0" with something that would trigger a value error, and then just wrap all of that within `IFERROR()`. That obviously fails since `SUBSTITUTE()` cannot be forced (to my knowledge) to check for full word match (so 100 would trigger the error).

Is this possible? I have thought for years it was not, but decided to put some thought back into it.

Comment: so: `=IFERROR(EXP(LN(FORMULA)),NA())`

Comment: You can always create a calculated column.

Comment: I often will do calculated columns in my own work, but people get annoyed when I recommend it in theirs. Great find, @ScottCraner. I have casually looked for this many times and never found that post. Do you think I should delete? Or would having this be helpful for others to locate the duplicate?

Comment: If you are okay with `#NUM` instead of `#N/A` you can shorten it to `EXP(LN(FORMULA))`

Comment: Always leave dups, it may come up first in another's search.

Comment: On second thought, this triggers the error for <=0, not just 0. I am going to tinker with the concept.

Comment: Using SUBSTITUTE: `=IFERROR(--TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(" " & FORMULA & " "," 0 ","")),NA())`

Comment: How about `=IFERROR(1/(1/(FORMULA)),NA())`

Comment: @chrisneilsen going to reopen the question, that is a better answer for this specific question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The general answer is

```
=IFERROR(f'(f(FORMULA)), AlternateValue)
```

where `f(FORMUALA)` returns an error (any error will do) for values of `FORMULA` that you want an alternate value for.

And `f'(...)` is the inverse of `f(...)`, so `f'(f(FORMULA))` returns `FORMULA` for other values.

Ensure the first function is applied to the whole of `FORMULA`. Enclosing it in `()` guarantees that.

Secondly, ensure the two functions are applied in the correct order, also achieved using `()`.

In this case you want an alternate value for `0` so you can use

```
=IFERROR(1/(1/(FORMULA)), NA())
```

Comment: This is great. Sometimes I find formulas easier to read and edit without all the nested parentheses, so I might use `=IFERROR(FORMULA^(-1)^(-1), NA())`

Comment: You need to ensure the first function is applied to the whole of FORMULA.  Enclosing it in () guarantees that.  Secondly you need to ensure the two functions are applied in the correct order, also achieved using ().  Your alternative would need to be `((FORMULA)^-1)^-1`

Answer (score 0):

Calculation and display can occur in two different locations - why merge operations when you don't need to?

A1 - `=Formula`
B1 - `=If(A1 = 0, NA(),A1)`